# Ember.JS Best Practice: Model vs Controller field binding

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am looking best practices in Ember.JS to fix the following scenario:

1. The user clicks on the **challenges** link.
2. The system displays the list of challenges.
3. The user clicks on **edit challenge** button.
4. The system displays the edit challenge form.
5. The user updates the challenge name.
6. The user clicks on the **leagues** link without saving the challenge.
7. The system displays the list of leagues.
8. The user clicks on the **challenges** link.
9. The system displays the list of challenges with the updated challenge name.

This issue is occurring because all my text field are binded directly to the challenge model and since the model is updated as soon as you type it updates the text on all the routes. I have a cancel button on the edit form where I do this.get('model').rollback() on the model to cancel out the edits. However this gets messy if you start doing rollback in different place on the page you can click.

The way I was thinking about fixing this issue is to have the form field binded to the controller properties and on each route copy the model properties to the controller properties on the setupController hook. This would prevent edits to impact the other routes.

I am wondering if this best practice in ember or is there a better way to fix this issue?

Thank you

Comment: There are other approaches, but it should be good enough to do the rollback in a single place, most likely the `willTransition` hook.

Comment: Some ppl solve it by creating copy of record and just throw it away instead of doing rollback. Its also worth to note that rollback will only rollback attributes and not relations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use single rollback in `deactivate` route hook. Then on `cancel` action you can do transition only.

```
// edit challenge route
model(params) {
  ...
},

deactivate() {
  this.modelFor( this.get('routeName')).rollback();
}
```

PS Are you aware that `rollback()` still doesn't work properly with relations and reduced to `rollbackAttributes()` in ED 2.0?

Related links: 
https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/2122
https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3273#issuecomment-110965145

Comment: No I didn't not know about the rollback issue, so I should be using rollbackAttributes in the deactivate hook?

Comment: There is no issue with rollback per se, just miscommunication. Rollback was renamed to rollbackAttributes because it only rollback attributes.

Comment: Keo, disagree with you.